# Find the mistake in my proof of partial derivatives exisiting implying differentiability.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

Let $\Omega\subseteq \mathbb{R} ^2$ be open. Let the function $f: \mathbb{R} ^2 \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ have partial derivatives $f_x'$ and $f'_y$ at every point in $\Omega$. I will now try to prove that $f$ is differentiable on $\Omega$.

What we want to show is the following:
$$
f(x+h,y+k) = f(x,y) + Ah + Bk + \sqrt{h^2+k^2}R(h,k) \qquad \text{(1)}
$$
for some $(x,y)\in\Omega$, $h$ and $k$ sufficiently small (so that $(x+h,y+k)\in\Omega$), some real numbers $A$ and $B$ and a function $R: \mathbb{R} ^2 \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ such that $R(h,k) \rightarrow 0$ when $(h,k) \rightarrow (0,0)$.

We introduce the following functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$:
$$
\phi(x)=f(x,y+k)
$$
$$
\psi(y) = f(x,y).
$$
*(Here comes the crucial step, is this the mistake?)*

We realize that, because the partial derivatives of $f$ exist, $\phi$ and $\psi$ are differentiable. Therefore we have:
$$
\phi(x+h) = \phi(x) + \phi'(x)h + h\rho_1(h)
$$
$$
\psi(y+k) = \psi(y) + \psi'(y)k + k\rho_2(k),
$$
where $\rho_1(h)\rightarrow 0$ when $h\rightarrow0$ and  $\rho_2(k)\rightarrow 0$ when $k\rightarrow0$.

Adding these together, noting that $\phi(x) = \psi(y+k)$, gives:
$$
\phi(x+h) = \psi(y) + \phi'(x)h + h\rho_1(h) + \psi'(y)k + k\rho_2(k),
$$
or:
$$
f(x+h,y+k) = f(x,y)  + f_x'(x,y+k)h + f_y'(x,y)k + h\rho_1(h) + k\rho_2(k).
$$
The above is on the form $(1)$ because, since $\lvert\frac{h}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}\rvert\leq1$ (and the same thing for $k$), we can set $R(h,k)= \frac{h\rho_1(h) + k\rho_2(k)}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}$ and see that $R(h,k) \rightarrow 0$ when $(h,k) \rightarrow (0,0)$. *(Right?)*

So we have shown that $f$ is differentiable.

---

Now, I know this has to be wrong (I've seen counterexamples). So either I have used somewhere that the partial derivatives are continuous, or I have made some other sort of reasoning error. It's just that I can't find it, so I would be thankful if someone could point it out for me! Thanks!

*I also know that $A$ and $B$ should be the partial derivatives at $(x,y)$, but in the definition of differentiability (at least in my text book) it only says they need to be some reals. Only later it's proven that they are in fact the partial derivatives - which makes my proof seem all the more fishy.*

Comment: What happens when you apply your argument to the counter examples you've seen?

Comment: I think the problem might be that when you set ϕ and ψ, you assume they are both differentiable, when they're not necessarily so (both of them might not even be continuous at all, considering they're just a composition, hence a "path through the graph of f").

Comment: @Julián: Thats not true. Since $f$ is partially differentiable, $\phi$ and $\psi$ are differentiable for each fixed $h$ and $k$. This is just the definition of partial differentiability!

Comment: You're right, I missed that completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your proof is, that $\rho_1$ depends on $k$! So if you have, for instance, something like $\rho_1(h)=\frac{h}{k}$, then
$$
R(h,k)=\frac{h^2/k+k\rho_2(k)}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}},
$$
which does not tend to 0 for $(h,k)\to(0,0)$. For example $R(h,h^2)\to\infty$ as $h\to0$.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: Can I ask a follow up question? In my text book, when they prove that functions with continuous partial derivatives are differentiable they use the mean value theorem twice to get $f(a+h,b+k) = f(a+b) + f_x'(a+\theta_1h,b+k)h + f_y'(a,b+\theta_2k)k$. They then go on with an argument to rewrite that using the continuity of the partial derivatives ($f_x'(a+\theta_1h,b+k) = f_x'(a,b) + \rho_1(h,k)$). Is this necessary due to the fact that $\theta_1,\theta_2$ are dependent on $h,k$?

Comment: Yes. Your $A$ above is then $f_x'(a,b)$ , but you only have $f_x'(a+\theta_1h,b+k)$, so you want to know how these two terms are related to each other. Since $f_x'$ is continuous at $(a,b)$, you can express $f_x'(a+\theta_1h,b+k)$ by $f_x'(a,b)$ and an error term $\rho_1(h,k)$ which goes to 0 as $h,k\to0$ (due to continuity!). Since $\theta_1$ depends on $h$ and $\theta_2$ on $k$, the error term depends on both $h$ and $k$.
Is that the answer to your question?

Comment: I think my question was why I can't just keep $f'_x(a+\theta_1h,b+k)$ as the $A$. But I get now that $A$ can't be dependent on $h$ or $k$.